# No low battery notification appears before premature low battery shutdown on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: power-management, asus, battery, notification

I was getting low battery notifications earlier when I installed initially, but it seems to broken now, my laptop (Asus) shuts down without any warning at 20% remaining battery.

I tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall indicator-power`, it worked for a single day only and again I am not getting any notifications.

Screenshots of my configuration:

[image: percentage-actions]
[image: time-based policy]

Comment: How old is the battery? Perhaps it's dying and/or not calibrated properly. It might say 20% remaining but in reality it may be almost empty.

Comment: yes, it is 4 years old, but why it works when i reinstall indicator-power, and later on suddenly stops

Comment: @pomsky I have mine for less than a year now and I am having the same issue.

Comment: It's answered under [No Low battery notification on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107397/no-low-battery-notification-on-ubuntu-18-04)