# No Low battery notification on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-power-manager

I have gone through other questions as well and somewhere it was mentioned that using percentage policy = true and `gsettings` to different level will work and it did work for some time until now. How to get back low power notification, my battery is broken btw.
[image: timer policy]

[image: percentage levels]

Answer (score 22):

Yes, the `gsettings` are ignored.

I've tested this on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and 20.04 LTS:

- Edit `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf` (case sensitive)
- Follow with: `sudo systemctl restart upower`

Comment: Do you mean by  edit `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf` that you edit `PercentageLow`, `PercentageCritical` and `PercentageAction` values because they have too little default values (10, 3, 2) and before they are reached your laptop turn off?

Comment: @Level_Up Yes, I've edited these, although not because of my laptop going dead. I just like to get the message sooner than 10%.

Comment: @kubanczyk worked! +1 given

Comment: This works for me too on Ubuntu 20.04. Here's the same answer but with a more detail: https://askubuntu.com/a/1261531/846736.